# Java, Bubble Sort, Arrays, Exception in thread "main" Error

Tags: java, arrays, exception, bubble-sort

I have a tutorial in class today with bubble sort and I've got an error I don't know how to fix.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at BubbleSorter.main(BubbleSorter.java:24)

It is not assessed but I would like to get through it to continue on.
Thank you. Below is my entire code.

```
public class BubbleSorter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        int array[] = { 12, 9, 4, 99, 120, 1, 3, 10 };
        System.out.println("Array Values before the sort:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        bubble_srt(array, array.length);

        System.out.print("Array Values after the sort:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            ;
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PAUSE");
    }

    private static void bubble_srt(int[] array, int length) {
        int i, j, t = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < (length - 1); j++) {
                if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                    t = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a small mistake:

This:

```
for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++);
System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

should be:

```
//                              v - Semicolon removed
for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

Comment: I imagine this is a formatting issue, otherwise I would have expected a different error message. i.e. `symbol i does not exist in Class X`

Comment: Well, `i` does exist, it was not declared in the for loop. This is kind of a gotcha I think.

Comment: In either case the array out of bounds is coming from the sort itself, not printing the array afterward.

Comment: I don't think so, see the method that the exception occurs in: `BubbleSorter.main(BubbleSorter.java:24)`

Comment: i is actually defined at the very top of the method - @Binyamin is correct, this is the cause of the problem

Comment: @SeanLandsman Well your bubble sort is wrong also, that is what I expected was the problem.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I tested. Binyamin is correct as to where the exception is thrown. OP also had a small error in logic

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Its not my bubble sort, but yes, I take your point.  I was simply confirming the the AOOB exception was due the extra ;

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input, I'll try to learn to format my code better. Should I have declared i inside the for loop?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always declare variables in the narrowest possible scope, in you case, you can do `for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

Also change

```
for (j = 1; j < (length - 1); j++) {
```

to

```
for (j = 1; j < length; j++) {
```

You left out the last element of the Array!

Output

```
Array Values before the sort:

12 9 4 99 120 1 3 10 

Array Values after the sort:
1 3 4 9 10 12 99 120 
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 2 lines

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        ;
System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
```

and

```
for (j = 1; j < (length - 1); j++) {
```

to

```
for (j = 1; j < (length); j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 18 you need to get rid of the ; or put in brackets {